# blender 2.8 flat color for 2d animation

Tags: shaders, color, compositing-nodes

I want to make some thing like 2d motion graphic with blender, i have done it with blender 2.79b without ligting but with nodes, *input RGB*, connected directly to *output*.

since next july blender 2.8 expected to release, so give it a try.

In 2.8 i realize that i cant connect directly form *input RGB* to *material output*.

**The question**

how do i replicate the condition on 2.79b to 2.8?

[image: on blender 2.79b]

[image: on blender 2.8 beta]

Comment: Is there any problem to connect to `Surface` socket? It should directly output the color in view-port and rendering

Comment: i tried it, but suddenly crash
but i tried it one more times, it works, thanks dude @Hikariztw

Comment: If you want to use alpha, then try transparent shader mix with color. Also need to set the material alpha setting to alpha blend (I didn't find another way to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use color in `surface` socket

The color will show up directly in render mode (both *Render* and *DevLook*)

And for alpha channel, the original alpha in RGB mode can't be the value in surface(might be a bug?) .An alternative way is use `transparent shader` with `mix shader` instead as shown below:

[image: node setting]

- the factor of `mix shader` can be the alpha value.
- **Blend mode** in Material setting should set to one of the alpha options
- Show backface will cause some problem, toggle it to see which one suit the scene

There might be a better way on this task